# using includes() in TypeScript returns more strings than expected

Tags: typescript

I have this code here:

```ts
getMembershipNameString(membership: string[]): any {
    const filtered = this.allMemberships.filter((m) => {
      return membership.includes(m.name);
    });
    return filtered;
  }
```

which should compare strings from one array with an array of objects. Let's say I have it like this:

`['Dog', 'Cat', 'Doggy']`

and the return result is both Dog and Doggy, whereas I would only like to it to return Dog.

I have also tried using:

```ts
getMembershipNameString(membership: string[]): any {
    const filtered = this.allMemberships.filter((m) => m.name === membership);
    console.log(filtered);
    return filtered;
  }
```

which gives me an error: **This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string[]' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)**

Thanks in advance!

P.S. my `allMemberships` object looks like this:
`{ name: 'name', label: 'label' }`;

Comment: What does your allMemberships object look like? Your second bit of code makes no sense as it's comparing a string to an array of strings which is why you get the ts error.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/fezpnchg/1/ , which compares an array of names to an array of objects with a name property. It filters as expected.